# Regex for find value between curly braces which have pipe separator

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = ({max_w} * {max_h} * {key|value}) / {key_1|value}
```

I have the above formula, I want to match the value with curly braces and which has a pipe separator. Right now the issue is it's giving me the values which have not pipe separator. I am new in regex so not have much idea about that. I tried below one

```
preg_match_all("^\{(|.*?|)\}^",$str, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

**It gives below output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => key|value
    [1] => max_w
    [2] => max_h
    [3] => key_1|value
)
```

**Expected output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => key|value
    [1] => key_1|value
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about PHP. Here's the general regex that will do this.

```
{([^{}]*\|[^{}]*)}
```

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ESTZd/1).

Comment: The second `[^{}]*?`  does not have to be lazy.

Comment: Yes, but then the question arises where to stop the first `[^{}]*`, before the first `|`, or the last `|` in between `{` and `}`? I would vote for the first scenario and use `{([^{}|]*)\|([^{}]*)}`

Comment: I considered that scenario. Guess you are going by the words `key` and `value` to mean one pair. I, however, took it that whatever is inside the braces needs to be returned, even if it has more than one `|`.

Comment: I see, I have just edited the comment above by adding *two* groups to the pattern to explain what I am driving at.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?<={)[^}]*\|[^}]*(?=})
```

For the given string the two matches are shown by the pointy characters:

```
({max_w} * {max_h} * {key|value}) / {key_1|value}
                      ^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zYsj7d/1)

`(?<={)` is a *positive lookbehind*. Arguably, the *positive lookahead* `(?=})` is not be needed if it is known that all braces appear in matching, non-overlapping pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `\{(|.*?|)\}` has 2 alternations `|` that can be omitted as the alternatives on the left and right of it are not really useful.

That leaves `\{(.*?)}` where the `.` can match any char including a pipe char, and therefore does not make sure that it is matched in between.

You can use a pattern that does not crosses matching a curly or a pipe char to match a single pipe in between.

```
{\K[^{}|]*\|[^{}|]*(?=})
```

- `{` Match opening `{`
- `\K` Forget what is matches until now
- `[^{}|]*` Match any char except the listed
- `\|` Match a `|` char
- `[^{}|]*` Match any char except the listed
- `(?=})` Assert a closing `}` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lLK1cE/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/cirfY)

```
$str = "({max_w} * {max_h} * {key|value}) / {key_1|value}";
$pattern = "/{\K[^{}|]*\|[^{}|]*(?=})/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => key|value
    [1] => key_1|value
)
```

Or using a capture group:

```
{([^{}|]*\|[^{}|]*)}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tcj4c4/1)